# POST javascript generated base64 image to different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, base64

I have image in base64 format what was generated by making screenshot of canvas by JavaScript.

I need POST this image to different page for processing (Not AJAX, normal redirect like form submit)

JQuery can create 'virtual' form and submit it, but it not work with files and when I set base64 image string into normal input it fails, because its too large.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form to accept large strings in inputs!

Example:

```
$.extend(
    {
        redirectPost: function (location, args) {
            var form = '';
            $.each(args, function (key, value) {
                form += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value="' + value + '">';
        });
        $('<form action="' + location + '" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' + form + '</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
    }
});
var redirect = "some/url/site.php"
$.redirectPost(redirect, {image: base64});
```